# How do I drop to the IRB prompt from a running script?

Tags: ruby, irb

Can I drop to an IRB prompt from a running Ruby script?

I want to run a script, but then have it give me an IRB prompt at a point in the program with the current state of the program, but not just by running rdebug and having a breakpoint.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you can use ruby-debug to get access to irb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ruby-debug'
x = 23
puts "welcome"
debugger
puts "end"
```

when program reaches debugger you will get access to irb.

Comment: Will this take the binding context into account?  Can I set the binding to something else?

Comment: This requires the `ruby-debug` gem, which doesn't work with Ruby 1.9.

Comment: for 1.9 you can use ruby-debug19 or the debugger gem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087610/ruby-debug-with-ruby-1-9-3

Answer (score 46):

[Pry](http://pry.github.com) (an IRB alternative) also lets you do this, in fact it was designed from the ground up for exactly this use case :)

It's as easy as putting `binding.pry` at the point you want to start the session:

```
require 'pry'
x = 10
binding.pry
```

And inside the session:

```
pry(main)> puts x
=> 10
```

Check out the website: http://pry.github.com

Pry let's you:

- drop into a session at any point in your code
- view method source code
- view method documentation (not using RI so you dont have to pre-generate it)
- pop in and out of different contexts
- syntax highlighting
- gist integration
- view and replay history
- open editors to edit methods using `edit obj.my_method` syntax

A tonne more great and original features

Comment: Thanks a lot, this should the at the top, I was on my way to use IRB for that

Answer (score 14):

apparently it requires a chunk of code to drop into irb.

Here's the link (seems to work well).

http://jameskilton.com/2009/04/02/embedding-irb-into-your-ruby-application

```
require 'irb'

module IRB
  def self.start_session(binding) # call this method to drop into irb
    unless @__initialized
      args = ARGV
      ARGV.replace(ARGV.dup)
      IRB.setup(nil)
      ARGV.replace(args)
      @__initialized = true
    end

    workspace = WorkSpace.new(binding)

    irb = Irb.new(workspace)

    @CONF[:IRB_RC].call(irb.context) if @CONF[:IRB_RC]
    @CONF[:MAIN_CONTEXT] = irb.context

    catch(:IRB_EXIT) do
      irb.eval_input
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Excellent find, thanks! This is exactly what I needed to access the class and instance variables in the context of where I invoked IRB.start_session(binding).

Answer (score 13):

This feature is available from Ruby 2.4. You can just use `binding.irb`

E.g.

```
require 'irb'
a = 10
binding.irb
puts a
```

If you run above code, you will get irb console, so that you can inspect values of local variables and anything else that is in scope.

Source: http://blog.redpanthers.co/new-binding-irb-introduced-ruby-2-4/

Ruby commit: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/493e48897421d176a8faf0f0820323d79ecdf94a

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to where you want the breakpoint:

`require 'ruby-debug';debugger`

but i suggest use pry instead of irb, which is super handy, insert the following line instead:

`require 'pry'; binding.pry`

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite late to the game but if you're loading a script from within irb/pry already, a simple `raise` also works to pop you back out to the irb/pry prompt. I use this quite often when writing one off scripts within the rails console.