# Re-using Ruby  DSL in a REPL or irb?

Tags: ruby, dsl, irb, read-eval-print-loop, instance-eval

I have developed a simple DSL for tasks on a UniVerse database in jruby. It looks something like this

```
support = { 
    :host => 'localhost', 
    :account => 'SUPPORT'
}

uni_task support do 
    connect
    exec "LIST FILE A1"
    disconnect
end
```

and is implemented like this

```
def uni_task(config, &block)
    session = UniSession.new
    session.instance_eval &block
end
```

I'm aware that you can drop to irb in a ruby script like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144560/drop-to-irb-prompt-from-ruby)

But is there a way to drop to a command line and have the scope changed to execute instance methods of an object by default?

Eg

```
irb> uni_commandline support
uni> connect
uni> exec "LIST FILE A1"

     .... output .....

uni> disconnect
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In irb you can use the `irb` command to move inside an object scope:

```
irb> irb some_object
```

from then on any commands will execute inside the scope of that object (so you can call its instance methods directly).