# ruby-debug with Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-debug

I just updated to Ruby 1.9.3p0 and Rails 3.1.1. Now when I try to launch the server, it complains that I should install `ruby-debug`, even though it's already installed.

```
% rails server --environment=development --debug
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
You need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode. With gems, use 'gem install ruby-debug'
Exiting
```

In my Gemfile I have

```
# see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083451/debugging-in-ruby-1-9
gem 'ruby-debug-base19', "0.11.24"
gem 'ruby-debug19', "0.11.6"
```

Is it possible to run debug with the latest version of Ruby?

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10414984/773690

Answer (score 102, accepted):

#### Update (April 28, 2012)

Try the new [debugger](http://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) gem as a replacement for ruby-debug.

<sup>([credit to @ryanb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087610/ruby-debug-with-ruby-1-9-3#comment12872326_8088498))</sup>

---

#### Update (March 2, 2012)

Installation of linecache19 and ruby-debug-base19 can be easily done with:

```
bash < <(curl -L https://raw.github.com/gist/1333785)
```

<sup>([credit to @fredostarr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8268091/211563))</sup>

---

#### Original answer

Have you looked at [ruby-debug19 on ruby-1.9.3-preview1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054948/ruby-debug19-on-ruby-1-9-3-preview1)?

> Here's a temporary solution:
>   http://blog.wyeworks.com/2011/11/1/ruby-1-9-3-and-ruby-debug
>
> Excerpt from the site:
>
> First download linecache19-0.5.13.gem and
>   ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem from
>   http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=8883, then …
>
> ```
> $ gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem 
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
> Successfully installed linecache19-0.5.13
> 1 gem installed
> $ gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/Users/santiago/.rbenv/source/ruby-1.9.3-p0  
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
> Successfully installed ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26
> 1 gem installed
> $ irb
> irb(main):001:0> require 'ruby-debug'
> => true
> ```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that these steps circumvent the `Gemfile`, adding a manual step before running `bundle install`. I've written up a solution that allows you run bundler normally here: http://git.io/72UfQg

Comment: Try the new "debugger" gem: `gem 'debugger'` https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger

Comment: Update: I've packaged these gems and put them on gemfury.  If using bundler, it's nice to have the --with-ruby-include remembered.

Comment: Debugger is awesome.  This works.  Mine answer hath jumped on own sword.

Comment: Here's how I was able to install it on my local box for rvm Ruby 1.9.3 :- https://gist.github.com/4132084. Hth..

Answer (score 33):

Installation of linecache19 and ruby-debug-base19 can be easily done with:

```
bash < <(curl -L https://raw.github.com/gist/1333785)
```

Comment: As well as this, for it to work in rails, I needed to add to my Gemfile 
`gem 'linecache19', '>= 0.5.13'
gem 'ruby-debug-base19', '>= 0.11.26'
gem 'ruby-debug19'`

Comment: Try the new "debugger" gem: `gem 'debugger'` https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger

Comment: @ryanb Thank you kind sir!  I was dreading trying to get rdebug working with 1.9.3 (and delayed_job was causing havoc with 1.9.2-p290)

Answer (score 5):

Someone else posted in a comment to try Pry, which is what I did.  This is what's necessary for Rails:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'pry-rails'


# In your Rails Project where you want a 'debugger'

puts 'i want to insert some code between this'

binding.pry

puts 'and this'
```

Immediately after installing I notice my `.irbrc` doesn't load, so I don't get pretty console output.  I also added this to my '~/.pryrc'

```
# setting up pry to have irb helpers like reload!
if defined?(Rails) && Rails.env
  extend Rails::ConsoleMethods
end
```

Pry has some nice features that I've wanted to check out, and I may yet return to ruby-debug once there's a simple way to integrate it into a Rails project for Ruby 1.9.3.  I can run the curl command from the other answers, but this is something I'll have to point my teammates to for our Rails project, so it doesn't scale well IMO.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not the definitive answer to this question, but I was lead here by a chain of closed duplicates.

For me the problem was that I run a project in both ruby 1.8 and ruby 1.9, and my Gemfile needed this change:

```
gem 'debugger', :require => 'ruby-debug', :platforms => :mri_19
gem 'ruby-debug', :platforms => :mri_18
```

Now it works for both rubies.

For more info see here: http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS-platforms-

Answer (score 2):

## For Windows Users:

First Download :linecache19-0.5.13.gem and ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem
From : http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=8883&release_id=46303

Assumption: Ruby is in c:\Ruby1.93

put the gem files downloaded to c:\temp
(linecache19-0.5.13.gem and ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem)

then execute from command line:

> gem install c:\temp\linecache19-0.5.13.gem
>
> gem install c:\temp\ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=C:\Ruby1.93\include\ruby-1.9.1\ruby-1.9.3-p0

Comment: The default path for Ruby Installer is C:\Ruby193.  Also, this requires the DevKit.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, if you use the newest patch for ruby1.9.3 (falcon, https://gist.github.com/1688857), use following commands

```
wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75414/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75415/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem

gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem
## with rvm: 
gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=$HOME/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon
## with rbenv (this is a guess): 
gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=$HOME/.rbenv/source/ruby-1.9.3-p0-falcon
```

Comment: Is anyone known to run this in production?

Comment: well. I would not trust it to run any big site... had too many slight edge-cases and this is just to bleeding-edge. wait a couple of months, most bugs should be ironed out till then. cheers!

Comment: Checked around: Falcon patch and friends are pretty awesome for speeding up local dev at least.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here :
[Ruby-debug not working - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9260206/889617)

It's about getting Ruby debugging to work with the following setup

- Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2
- Aptana Studio 3 (Build 3.0.8.201201201658)
- Using rvm, in my project working directory I have a .rvmrc stating:

  ```
  rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p0@mygemset
  ```

Basically, I had to use :

```
linecache19 (0.5.13)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre10)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.16)
```

Note that I'm not using ruby-debug-base19 but ruby-debug-base19x

I hope this helps!

-- Freddy

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to check if the gem 'ruby_source_code' is already installed.

Check: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/1857#note-8

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have rvm and assuming you ruby installation is in /usr/local/ruby-1.9.3-po your can use this command:

curl -L https://raw.github.com/gist/1533750 | sudo /bin/bash