# Debug Not Working After Upgrade To Ruby 1.9.3 And Rails 3.2.2

Tags: ruby-debug, ruby-1.9.3

I have upgraded my app to use Ruby 1.9.3p0 and Rails 3.2.2. To get bundler working I changed this:

```
gem 'ruby-debug'
```

to this:

```
gem 'ruby-debug19'
```

Now `rails server` gives:

```
Could not find archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2 in any of the sources 
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Running `bundle install` does not help.  The error goes away when I remove `ruby-debug19` gem from my Gemfile, but then debugging does away too.

I also tried changing the Gemfile to:

```
gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

No help.  I'm kinda new to Rails, so maybe it's something obvious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby-debug with Ruby 1.9.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087610/ruby-debug-with-ruby-1-9-3)

Comment: yeap.. this works for me "bash < <(curl -L https://raw.github.com/gist/1333785)"

Comment: No that does not work.  Tried it.  Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2011/11/1/ruby-1-9-3-and-ruby-debug).