# Install autoreconf on OS X v10.7 (Lion)?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, rvm, ruby-debug

I'm attempting to [re-install Ruby 1.9.3 with a patch that will allow me to use ruby-debug](https://github.com/chuckg/chuckg.github.com/blob/master/ruby/193_and_rdebug.md).

When following the instructions and running

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --patch debug --force-autoconf
```

It runs through and after applying the patch spits out:

> rvm requires autoreconf to install the selected ruby interpreter however autoreconf was not found in the PATH.

Unfortunately, googling around for how to install autoreconf on OS X v10.7 (Lion) (or much information about it at all) seems to be a dead end.

Comment: You don't have to patch 1.9.3 to use ruby-debug—see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087610/ruby-debug-with-ruby-1-9-3).

Comment: other thing is you most likely used `command line tools` which is missing `auto*` tools, and provides only LLVM compiler - no real GCC, that will be a problem when compiling ruby-1.9.3-p0 or lower versions

Answer (score 370, accepted):

If you are using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29), try

```
brew install automake
```

Which should also install `autoconf` and allow `rvm` to finish installing.

Comment: `brew` isn't included with OSX, but you can get it here: http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Comment: I think this moved, I required: `brew install autoconf`

Comment: libtool also needed,
brew install libtool
without it you will get configure.ac:14: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL

Comment: To install homebrew, just visit http://brew.sh/, or https://github.com/Homebrew/brew

Comment: Just did this, `autoconf` is installed as a dependency of `automake` cc: @XavierShay

Answer (score 44):

If you want to do this using [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts) instead of [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29), you can do:

```
sudo port install automake autoconf libtool
```

I had the same problem and this solved it for me.

Comment: This didn't seem to add autoconf to my path.

Comment: Hey Erik, are you sure macports is setup correctly? Can you see /opt/local/bin and related directories in your path?

Comment: In case someone has problem with libtool and glibtool, this is the way it has been ported in macports:
https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2009-October/017432.html

Answer (score 9):

If you're using `brew`, then the `autoreconf` utility is part of the `autoconf` package, so install it via:

```
brew install autoconf
```

If the problem persists, consider either `reinstall` or `link` it again. Use `locate autoreconf` to find out where it is.

Also check if `/usr/local/bin/autoreconf` exists (and is linked into the right place), and you've the `/usr/local/bin` path added in your `/etc/paths` file.

Answer (score 2):

By downloading the [`.pkg file from MacPorts`](http://www.macports.org/install.php) and installing it, it does the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but because Homebrew moved away from the Cellar directory, but for some reasons binaries of this package were still there.

I reinstalled autoconf with the following command and autoreconf is in the right PATH now: `brew reinstall autoconf`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my autoreconf problem adding the path to my shell:

```
sudo pico /etc/paths
```

then I added the line

```
/sw/bin
```

where I found the `autoreconf` and autoconf files and saved everything.

Since then I can use autoreconf without any problems.

Comment: I don't see to have a /sw/bin on my osx machine.  Would you mind explaining where that came from?