# Autoconf Install Error

Tags: php, mamp, autoconf

while installing autoconf on my mac i receive the following error:

```
M-MBP:autoconf-2.69 marcus$ sudo make install
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  install-recursive
Making install in bin
test -z "/usr/local/bin" || ../build-aux/install-sh -c -d "/usr/local/bin"
 /usr/bin/install -c autom4te autoconf autoheader autoreconf ifnames autoscan autoupdate '/usr/local/bin'
install: /usr/local/bin/autom4te: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [install-binSCRIPTS] Error 71
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Comment: are you sure that autoconf is installed?

Comment: It seems "install" was not found on your system. What output does "type -a install" produce?

Answer (score 2):

It would help tremendously if you can specify a little bit more of what system you are using.

This might give you insights if you are running on yosemite. 
   http://jsdelfino.blogspot.com/2012/08/autoconf-and-automake-on-mac-os-x.html

If you have homebrew installed, try following what this user has suggested. [Install autoreconf on OSX lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575989/install-autoreconf-on-osx-lion).

This might solve your problem as well: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94216/brew-uses-usr-bin-autom4te-in-stead-of-usr-local-bin-autom4te. Comment below if you find more errors or so.