# fatal: program autoreconf is required but was not found

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, ghcjs

I followed the installation of GHCJS and when I came to the step "Build the libraries" and I typed the command `ghcjs-boot --dev`
But I get the following lines in my Terminal

```
(lines omitted)...
generating configure script for ./boot/base
MyDir/.ghcjs/x86_64-darwin-0.1.0-7.8.3/ghcjs/ghcjs-boot/boot/base$ [autoreconf]: <not found> 
fatal: program autoreconf is required but was not found
name searched for (from boot.yaml or command line): autoreconf
searched in PATH:
MyDir/Haskell/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:MyDir/Haskell/bin
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: You need to install `autoreconf`, I can't help with OS X installation, but I am pretty sure you would be able to find the instructions in the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system is lacking the `auto(re)conf` tool which is (unfortunately) not installed with XCode any more. There is an old post explaining how to install `auto(re)conf` on OS X manually:

[Install autoreconf on OSX lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575989/install-autoreconf-on-osx-lion)

Answer (score 3):

Just to make life a bit easier for subsequent users who landed here.

If you have already installed homebrew,

`brew install automake` will install the autoreconf for you.