# Error while building tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, autoconf, macos-sierra, android-build

I am getting 'autoreconf missing error' while building tensorflow from android studio.

OS: MacOs Sierra.

```
+ autoreconf -f -i -Wall,no-obsolete
./autogen.sh: line 48: autoreconf: command not found

:TensorFlow-Android-Inference:buildTensorflow FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

How can I fix this? 
Tried brew install autoconf but it didn't work.

**SOLUTION:** fix `task buildTensorflow`'s `environment`  line (added `/usr/local/bin:`)

Comment: Have you tried [installing the autoreconf](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9782529/1951176)?

Comment: @sygi Yes I have already installed.

Comment: @Vardan95 It's okay to post your own solution as an answer and accept it. That way, others know that the question has already been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by the OP:  The task in which you build TensorFlow needed to have `/usr/local/bin` in the PATH for `task buildTensorflow`'s environment.