# Can't debug ruby 1.9.3 with Netbeans and ubuntu

Tags: ruby, debugging

I'm a totally beginner with Ruby. Today I tried to set up a development environment. Therefore I have installed rvm and with it ruby and rails. As an IDE I have decided to use Netbeans (7.0).
Now I'm trieng (for hours...) to debug a simple testfile, but it's not working. The IDE has offered me to install the fast Debugger, but this can't be done, because of some error.
(It tells me that it failed to build gem native extension)
If I try to use the normal (=the slow debuger) nothing happens at all.
Here is the output of the failed installation:

```
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

If you have doubt: I'm a DAU when it comes to ruby... .

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby-debug with Ruby 1.9.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087610/ruby-debug-with-ruby-1-9-3)

Comment: Don't think so. I've edited the initial posting so you can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans 7.0 dropped support for Ruby - http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/01/ruby-dropped-in-netbeans-7

Boo Netbeans!!!!!   I used 6.9 for a while, that definitely works if you can get a copy?

Personally I use [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) with the [guard package](https://github.com/cyphactor/sublime_guard) &/or the terminal these days.  A lot of people use Textmate, Vim or Emacs as well.

Comment: I use RubyMine. It's not free, but it is reasonably priced.

Comment: Up-to-date list of popular editors here - http://gopollgo.com/what-is-your-primary-text-editor-for-ruby-slash-rails

Comment: Cool. Although by now, I just use vim. I have to say, it really get's the job done. Autocomplete, autoindent, syntax highlighting, and all kinds of advanced features I can't eve pretend to understand.

Comment: Is it possible to get run the debugger in aptana studio 3?